# "No Log sinks are configured" when trying to export logs

Tags: logging, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I was trying to export logs from Stackdriver Logging interface.

I clicked "Logs" from the left menu, and then Exports, now I see a message saying: "No Log sinks are configured."

I tried looking at [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export#exported-logs-permissions) and there was nothing relevant there, actually this is the first appearance of the string "No Log sinks are configured." in Google search.

**EDIT:**

Another approach, using the Cloud Shell, I typed the following command:

```
$ gcloud beta logging sinks create direct-log storage.googleapis.com/log_export_bucket --log compute.googleapis.com/syslog

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.logging.sinks.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

Comment: For gcloud, some basic questions:
- is gcloud pointing to the correct GCP project?
- is the logging API enabled?

Comment: And does the bucket have the group cloud-logs@google.com as an OWNER?

Comment: Yes for both but there's nothing special about that bucket, just added permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Logging configuration

The `PERMISSION_DENIED` gcloud errors suggests the account from which you are trying to create this sink does not have a **Project Owner** role or **Logs Configuration Writer** role.  These are of course required as mentioned in the [documentation you've already referenced](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#before_you_begin).  To see if this is in place, you can inspect a given account's roles using [Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) and ensure the account currently logged in has the proper roles.  At this point, the **CREATE EXPORT** should be available to click under **Stackdriver Logging** - **Logs**.

### Selection a destination

At this point, you'll need to set up a destination such as a Cloud Storage bucket with appropriate permissions `cloud-logs@google.com`.  According to [Creating sinks](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#creating_sinks) however, this will be done for you when creating the sink.

> As part of creating the sink, Stackdriver Logging will first grant itself (cloud-logs@google.com) permission to write to your destination.

Nevertheless, you can verify that `cloud-logs@google.com` was granted the appropriate permission in Cloud IAM to ensure Stackdriver Logging will be authorized to write to the given destination.  In the case of Cloud Storage, `cloud-logs@google.com` requires **Owner** permissions to the specified bucket as describe in [Destination authorization](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#destination_authorization).

> In Cloud Storage, the group cloud-logs@google.com is given Owner permission to your bucket.

Note that using these destinations will most likely require you to enable billing.

---

### Further errors

The above steps are all that is required to create a sink and setup log exporting.  If you've verified all aforementioned credentials/permissions and still face the same error(s), I would suggest filing a defect report on the [Google Cloud Platform public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list).  We can reach out at that point and privately inspect the privileges setup to investigate this behavior that differs from the documentation.

Comment: After realizing I might not have the appropriate permissions I asked a project owner doing the same steps, he experienced the same problem, I did use your advice regarding the bug reporting: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=1454
– 
I guess we can wait and see what can Google's engineers tell us about that.

Comment: This mailing list is gcloud and SDK only, they can't help with this issue.

Comment: My apologies.  I linked to the incorrect issue tracker.  My intention was to direct to the [Google Cloud Platform public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list).  Along with the link in this comment, I've also updated the answer.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two things going on in this situation.

1. In the UI, the "No Log sinks are configured" message is just informing you that no export rules have been set up yet. To set them up, you go to the main logging view, choose the logs you want to export by filtering for them, and click "Create Export" to create them.

[image: Screenshot showing the location of the Create Export button in the Stackdriver Logging user interface]

2. The message you're getting from gcloud suggests that you may not have permissions on the project you're trying to edit to create new export sinks. Is this a project you own? If not, the owner needs to grant you the "Logs Configuration Writer" role (and possibly also the "Logs Viewer" role, so you can see the logs you're trying to export before you create the export rule to make sure they're the ones you intend to export).

Comment: The "Create Export" button is grayed out, the owner itself was unable to do so, Google Documentation shows that the "Create Export" option should open when clicking the Log Export link on the left panel.